# Distance between unequal number of locations in R (latitude and longitude are inputs)

Tags: r, distance, ggmap

How do I calculate the distance between each location in one data frame versus each in another when they have a different number of rows?

For example, say I have dataframe **A** with 3 rows and dataframe **B** with 4 rows. These are from the SNAP (United States federal food / beverage assistance for low-income households) [Retailer Locator](https://www.fns.usda.gov/snap/retailerlocator) :

```
A
      Store_Name     Longitude Latitude
1     Food Lion 2213 -80.86581 35.59477
2 THE CORNER GROCERY -81.09917 35.26776
3          FISH WING -80.88245 35.21639


B
         Store_Name     Longitude Latitude
1    SUPERIOR GROCERIES -79.80839 35.73597
2     MORVEN TRUCK STOP -80.01122 34.88312
3       GREENHILL STORE -81.99146 35.34768
4 NORTHSIDE FOOD MARKET -77.94242 34.24158
```

Here are some failed attempts:

```
mapdist(as.character(a), as.character(b)) </code>
```

YIELDS: from and to entries that resemble the following and only one distance calculation that is possibly useful: `c(35.594765, 35.267761, 35.216393)`

```
distcomp <- mapdist(from = c(lon = as.character(a$Longitude), lat = as.character(a$Latitude)), to = c(lon = as.character(b$Longitude),   lat = as.character(b$Latitude)), mode = "driving")
```

YIELDS: `Error <code> arguments imply differing number of rows: 6, 8`

```
# row-bind the rows even though this would mean extra work so that I could only have the distances from those in <code>a</code> to those in <code>b</code>:

c <- rbind(a,b)
distcomp <- mapdist(from = c(lon = as.character(c$Longitude), lat = as.character(c$Latitude)), 
                     to = c(lon = as.character(c$Longitude),   lat = as.character(c$Latitude)), mode = "driving")
```

YIELDS: A bunch of NAs in the results. Nothing helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can merge the tables together so that every row of each table is joined to every row on the other table (often referred to as a full-join), and then calculate the distances between each set of lat/lon coordinates.

In your question it appears you're asking for the driving distance, as given by Google Maps. Here I'm giving both the driving and the haversine distance.

---

#### Joining the data

```
## create a key column to join on
A$key <- 1
B$key <- 1

## Join together
AB <- merge(A, B, by = "key")
```

---

#### Distance Calculation - haversine

```
## Here I'm using the haversine distance calculation from geosphere
library(geosphere)

AB$distance <- distHaversine(p1 = matrix(c(AB$Longitude.x, AB$Latitude.x), ncol = 2),
                             p2 = matrix(c(AB$Longitude.y, AB$Latitude.y), ncol = 2))


head(AB)
#   key     Store_Name.x Longitude.x Latitude.x        Store_Name.y Longitude.y Latitude.y  distance
# 1   1     FoodLion2213   -80.86581   35.59477   SUPERIORGROCERIES   -79.80839   35.73597  96915.65
# 2   1     FoodLion2213   -80.86581   35.59477     MORVENTRUCKSTOP   -80.01122   34.88312 110963.56
# 3   1     FoodLion2213   -80.86581   35.59477      GREENHILLSTORE   -81.99146   35.34768 105691.88
# 4   1     FoodLion2213   -80.86581   35.59477 NORTHSIDEFOODMARKET   -77.94242   34.24158 306403.99
# 5   1 THECORNERGROCERY   -81.09917   35.26776   SUPERIORGROCERIES   -79.80839   35.73597 128061.51
# 6   1 THECORNERGROCERY   -81.09917   35.26776     MORVENTRUCKSTOP   -80.01122   34.88312 107968.35
```

---

#### Distance calculation - Google Maps driving

To use Google maps distances you can use `mapdist` from `ggmap` as you were doing (but for some reason I could only get it to work in an `apply` function)

```
library(ggmap)

mdist <- apply(AB, 1, function(x){
    f = as.numeric(c(x[['Longitude.x']], x[['Latitude.x']]))
    t = as.numeric(c(x[['Longitude.y']], x[['Latitude.y']]))
    mapdist(f, t)
})

AB$mapDist <- do.call(rbind, mdist)

head(AB)
# key     Store_Name.x Longitude.x Latitude.x        Store_Name.y Longitude.y Latitude.y  distance
# 1   1     FoodLion2213   -80.86581   35.59477   SUPERIORGROCERIES   -79.80839   35.73597  96915.65
# 2   1     FoodLion2213   -80.86581   35.59477     MORVENTRUCKSTOP   -80.01122   34.88312 110963.56
# 3   1     FoodLion2213   -80.86581   35.59477      GREENHILLSTORE   -81.99146   35.34768 105691.88
# 4   1     FoodLion2213   -80.86581   35.59477 NORTHSIDEFOODMARKET   -77.94242   34.24158 306403.99
# 5   1 THECORNERGROCERY   -81.09917   35.26776   SUPERIORGROCERIES   -79.80839   35.73597 128061.51
# 6   1 THECORNERGROCERY   -81.09917   35.26776     MORVENTRUCKSTOP   -80.01122   34.88312 107968.35
# mapDist.from                                       mapDist.to mapDist.m
# 1 507-543 NC-150, Mooresville, NC 28117, USA 1504N N Fayetteville St, Asheboro, NC 27203, USA    118648
# 2 507-543 NC-150, Mooresville, NC 28117, USA                2876 US-52, Morven, NC 28119, USA    135294
# 3 507-543 NC-150, Mooresville, NC 28117, USA   136 Firethorn Ln, Rutherfordton, NC 28139, USA    149211
# 4 507-543 NC-150, Mooresville, NC 28117, USA      603 Red Cross St, Wilmington, NC 28401, USA    359219
# 5  101 McAdenville Rd, Lowell, NC 28098, USA 1504N N Fayetteville St, Asheboro, NC 27203, USA    160581
# 6  101 McAdenville Rd, Lowell, NC 28098, USA                2876 US-52, Morven, NC 28119, USA    137167
# mapDist.km mapDist.miles mapDist.seconds mapDist.minutes mapDist.hours
# 1    118.648      73.72787            5049        84.15000      1.402500
# 2    135.294      84.07169            5574        92.90000      1.548333
# 3    149.211      92.71972            5812        96.86667      1.614444
# 4    359.219     223.21869           13264       221.06667      3.684444
# 5    160.581      99.78503            5782        96.36667      1.606111
# 6    137.167      85.23557            5639        93.98333      1.566389
```

Comment: Noting that I observed distHaversine to provide the distance in meters in case anyone looks at @SymbolixAU's output and wonders about its unit-of-measurement. mapdist explicitly provides kilometers (km) and miles.